# char and the usual arithmetic conversion rules

Tags: c, types, type-conversion

I know this question has been asked and seemingly answered a gazillion times over but I can't seem to match the answers to my own experience.

The C standard specifies that for addition "both operands shall have arithmetic type" (6.5.6.1). Arithmetic types covers integer and floating types (6.2.5.18) and finally integer types are char, short, int, long and long long which exist as signed and unsigned types (6.2.5.4 and 6.2.5.6). According to the rules for usual arithmetic conversion "If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed." So far so good.

It has been my understanding, as exemplified here from "The C Book", that "[n]o arithmetic is done by C at a precision shorter than int" which is where integral promotion is applied. I can find no reference to this in the standard but I seem to have seen this numerous times.

Since unsigned char is an arithmetic type and the rules for usual arithmetic conversion states that operands of the same type does not need conversion, why the need for integral promotion?

I tested this using two different compilers. I wrote a simple program which does char addition:

```
unsigned char a = 1;
unsigned char b = 2;
unsigned char c = a + b;
```

The target platform is an Atmel Mega8 uC using an 8 bit architecture. An integer addition would therefore require use of two registers if the operands should be subject to integral promotion.

Compiling this using an Imagecraft AVR compiler with no optimization and with strict and ANSI C portability options enabled yields this assembly code:

```
mov R16, R20
add R16, R18
```

Using avr-gcc (I am not aware of an ANSI switch similar to gcc's -strict):

```
$ avr-gcc -O0 -mmcu=atmega8 -S -c main.c
```

The resulting assembly:

```
ldd r25,Y+1
ldd r24,Y+2
add r24,r25
std Y+3,r24
```

The resulting code in both cases operates on a single byte. I get similar results for bitwise | and & and logical || and &&. Does this mean then that the standard allows arithmetic operations on character types without integral promotion or does it simply mean that these compilers are not standard complient?

---

Additional:

Turns out it all depends on the type the result is stored in. The example shown above is only true when the result is stored in a char, and it does not depend on the result of the addition. Setting a to 0xFF and b to 1 produces the exact same assembly code.

If the type of `c` is changed to unsigned int the resulting assembly looks like this:

```
mov R2,R20
clr R3
mov R16,R18 
clr R17
add R16,R2 
adc R17,R3
```

Even in the case where the result can be held in a single byte, i.e. a=1 and b=2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C 2011 (n1570) 6.3.1.8 (“Usual arithmetic conversions”) 1 states that the integer promotions are performed *before* considering whether the types are the same:

> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
> > If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed…

Thus, in the C abstract machine, `unsigned char` values must be promoted to `int` before arithmetic is performed. (There is an exception for perverse machines where `unsigned char` and `int` have the same size. In this case, `unsigned char` values are promoted to `unsigned int` rather than `int`. This is esoteric and need not be considered in normal situations.)

In the actual machine, operations must be performed in a way that gets the same results *as if* they were performed in the abstract machine. Because only the results matter, the actual intermediate operations do not need to exactly match the abstract machine.

When the sum of two `unsigned char` values is assigned to an `unsigned char` object, the sum is converted to a `unsigned char`. This conversion essentially discards bits beyond the bits that fit in an `unsigned char`.

This means that the C implementation gets the same result whether it does this:

- Convert values to `int`.
- Add values with `int` arithmetic.
- Convert result to `unsigned char`.

or this:

- Add values with `unsigned char` arithmetic.

Because the result is the same, the C implementation may use either method.

For comparison, we can consider this statement instead: `int c = a + b;`. Also, suppose the compiler does not know the values of `a` and `b`. In this case, using `unsigned char` arithmetic to do the addition could yield a different result than converting the values to `int` and using `int` arithmetic. E.g., if `a` is 250 and `b` is 200, then their sum as `unsigned char` values is 194 (250 + 200 % 256), but their sum in `int` arithmetic is 450. Because there is a difference, the C implementation **must** use instructions that get the correct sum, 450.

(If the compiler did know the values of `a` and `b` or could otherwise prove that the sum fit in an `unsigned char`, then the compiler could again use `unsigned char` arithmetic.)

Comment: What you call esoteric (`sizeof(char)=sizeof(int)`) is a real-life scenario for those programming something like 16-bit TI DSPs, where the minimum addressable unit of data memory is 16 bit, so no 8-bit chars.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the relevant part from C99:

> **6.3.1 Arithmetic operands**
>   **6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers**
>   1 Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows:
>   ...
>   2 The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may be used:
>   — An object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is less than the rank of int and unsigned int.
>   — A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>   If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

I agree it's obscure, but this is the closest you can find w.r.t. conversion of the various kinds of `char` or `short` or `_Bool` to `int` or `unsigned int`.

From the same source:

> **5.1.2.3 Program execution**
>   In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object).
>   ...
>   10 EXAMPLE 2 In executing the fragment
>   char c1, c2;
>   /* ... */
>   c1 = c1 + c2;
>   the ‘‘integer promotions’’ require that the abstract machine promote the value of each variable to int size and then add the two ints and truncate the sum. Provided the addition of two chars can be done without overflow, or with overflow wrapping silently to produce the correct result, the actual execution need only produce the same result, possibly omitting the promotions.

Answer (score 2):

In 6.3.1.8 (usual arithmetic conversions, n1570), we can read

> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:

so integer promotion is part of the usual arithmetic conversions for integer types.

Thus in the abstratc machine, the conversion to `(unsigned) int` must be done.

But by the "as if" rule, if the behaviour is indistinguishable from that by strictly implementing the abstract machine, the implementation may do things differently.

So if it is guaranteed that the computation using only single bytes has the same result as the computation promoting to `int`, the implementation is allowed to use single-byte arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

If the computer is capable of performing operations on types smaller than `int`, then by all means the standard will *never* prevent it. Keep in mind that the standard tries to keep as many options available to the compilers and leaves the decision to choose the best method up to them.

The phrase *"no arithmetic is done by C at a precision shorter than int"* is also correct. If you pay close attention, you will see that the arithmetic is indeed done at a precision that is no shorter than `int`. That doesn't mean however that the compiler is forced to do an integer promotion as it can safely perform the operation in your example program on bytes and get the same precision.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no contradiction here. The compiler is not obliged to follow any specific computation path as long as the observable result is *as if* it would follow the prescribed way.

In particular, for your case, if we would do the computation with promotion to int (say, to 16 bit): `a` promoted to `int` has the same value, so does `b` as well. The value of `a + b` is actually `(a + b) mod 2^16`, but we assign this to an unsigned char, which is truncating the upper 8 bits, that is the same as taking the result `mod 2^8`: `((a + b) mod 2^16) mod 2^8 = (a + b) mod 2^8`.

The calculation without integer promotion would result in `(a + b) mod 2^8`, which is exactly the same.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Although the example in the question, storing the sum of two `char` objects in another `char` object is the same whether performed in unsigned `char` arithmetic or `int` arithmetic, the question asks about the rules in general, not just for this specific example. If we consider the result of assigning the sum of two `char` objects to an `int`, then the conversion rules do make a difference if the sum exceeds the maximum value of a char.

Comment: @Eric: I don't agree with your opinion. The OP presents the seeming contradiction, I explain that there is no contradiction (however without mentioning exact chapter of C specs, I am not a specs ninja). In contrast, your answer just cites the specs, without explaining why the actual compiler is behaving a different way.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Can I get you to include your comment in your answer, as that exactly answers the behavior I am seeing. I have verified this and will add this to the question above.

Comment: @Vlad This does not answer why the same thing happens if a set a to 0xFF and b to 1. The carry is not used.

Comment: @Kenneth: why, 0x100 mod 2^8 is 0.

Comment: @Vlad I was just formulating a lengthy response before I read your answer again and you are of course right. I suppose I got confused by all the modding.

Comment: @Kenneth: I added to my existing answer, so that now it both describes the promotion and conversion rules and explains why the compiler may use `unsigned char` arithmetic even though the operands are conceptually converted to `int`.