# What is -(-128) for signed single byte char in C?

Tags: c, cpu, instruction-set

My little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    signed char c = -128;
    c = -c;
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

print:

```
-128
```

Is minus (-) operator portable across CPU?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The operand of the unary minus first undergoes standard promitions, so it is of type `int`, which can represent the value `-128`. The result of the operation is the value `128`, also of type `int`. The conversion from `int` to `signed char`, being a narrowing of signed types, is implementation-defined.

(Your implementation seems to do a simple wrap-around: 125, 126, 127, -128, -127, ...)

Comment: Does ANSI C convert primitive types to **int** before performing arithmetical operations? This is true for Java (as states Java lang spec), but is this true for C?

Comment: @gavenkoa May be your answer: [C 2011 (n1570) 6.3.1.8 (“Usual arithmetic conversions”) 1 states that the integer promotions are performed before considering whether the types are the same:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841278/char-and-the-usual-arithmetic-conversion-rules)

Comment: @gavenkoa: Loosely speaking, everything that's "smaller" than an `int` is promoted to `int` during arithmetic operations. The result is then assigned back to the left-hand side.

Comment: @gavenkoa: Types that have a lower conversion rank than `int` are promoted to `int`, unless `int` cannot represent all the values of the original type, in which case they are promoted to `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 4):

Note: `-128` in 2's complement is `1000 0000` (in one byte) and `128` is also `1000 0000` . 
If you do `char c = 128` and print it it will be `-128` because of the following reason:

A char variable = 128 value stores in memory as follows.

```
MSB
+----+----+----+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1 |  0 | 0  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   
+----+----+----+---+---+---+---+---+
   7    6   5    4   3   2   1   0
```

Now,

1. this value will be interpreted as negative value because MSB is `1`,
2. to print magnitude of  this -ve number 2's complement needed, that is also `128` in one byte so output is: `-128`

   2's complement:

   ```
     1000 0000

     0111 1111  1's complement 
   + 0000 0001 
    -----------
     1000 0000  2's complement   

    Magnitude = 128 
    So in one byte 128 == -128
   ```

Answer (score 1):

because a byte(char) can't hold 128

```
-128 = 0x80
```

what neg do is reverse it and plus 1

```
-(-128) = (~0x80) + 1 = 0x7F + 1 = 0x80
```

daha, you got 0x80 again