# Char data type arithmetic expression

Tags: c

```
int main()

{

        char a = 'P';  

        char b = 0x80;  

        printf("a>b  %s\n",a>b ? "true":"false");  

        return 0;

}
```

Why does it evaluates to true?

Comment: The ASCII value of `P` happens to be (decimal) 80. Did you confuse decimal `80` vs. hexadecimal `0x80`?

Comment: read [What is -(-128) for signed single byte char in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469804/what-is-128-for-signed-single-byte-char-in-c/17469941#17469941)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On your system, `char` is signed. It is also eight bits, so `0x80` overflows what a signed 8-bit integer can represent. The resulting value is -128. Since `P` is some positive value, it is greater than -128.

C permits the `char` type to be signed or unsigned. This is a special (annoying) property, unlike other integer types such as `int`. It is often advisable to explicitly declare character types with `unsigned char` so that the behavior is more determined rather than implementation-dependent.

Comment: Assuming ASCII, `P` is 0x50.

Comment: @user2712068 Assuming two's complement, it'll be -127.

Comment: @DennisMeng: I have no knowledge of whether the OP’s system is using ASCII, and this assumption is not necessary for the problem. Per C 2011 (N1570) 6.2.5 3, characters of the execution character set are nonnegative.