# What does the compiler do here: int a = b * (c * d * + e)?

Tags: c++, arithmetic-expressions

I had a strange bug in my program, and after a few hours of debugging, I found the following very stupid line:

```
int a = b * (c * d *  + e)
```

If you don't see it: Between `d` and `e` I wrote `* +`, where just a `+`was intended.

Why does this compile and what does it actually mean?

Comment: Uses: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3182557/962089 In addition, there's printing (or otherwise using) the integral value of a character type: `std::cout << +c;` If this happens a lot, `static_cast` gets very cluttery.

Comment: Hint: what if you had intended to write a minus?

Comment: What if the type of `e`?

Comment: What does `2 × (3 × 4 × +5)` do in normal arithmetic?

Comment: This isn't a question about programming so much as it's a question about reading basic math notation.

Comment: @Boann I think the question isn't as trivial as all that. Not all "basic math notations" work in programming. We all know that thinking in terms of math when programming is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour and I've seen, as I've already told y'all, *dozens* of them, most of them concerning C#/Java/JS/Python, but a couple of them also mentioning C directly. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637005/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-unary-operator-in-c - would that Q/A fit your "exact duplicate", or do I have to dig through http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=unary%20plus further? believe me or not, this **has** been asked before... **dozens** of times in **dozens** of flavours.

Comment: @vaxquis that one is actually much better but it is marked as `C` and since this one already has C++ specific answers we should not change this tag.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The `+` is interpreted as an unary plus operator. It simply returns the [promoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805580/does-unary-operator-do-type-conversions/24805967#24805967) value of its operand.

Comment: For more detail on "promoted", [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24805967/1505939)

Comment: The effect of this is identical to `int a = b * (c * d * (+e))`

Answer (score 27):

Unary `+` returns the promoted value.
Unary `-` returns the negation:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6;
unsigned int c = 3;

std::cout << (a * +b); // = 30
std::cout << (a * -b); // = -30
std::cout << (1 * -c); // = 4294967293 (2^32 - 3)
```

Comment: "Positive value" is misleading. That makes it sound like it returns the absolute value of the operand, which is not the case.

Comment: Nor does `-` necessarily return "the negative value": `int b = -5; std::cout << -b;`

Comment: @MSalters thank you, corrected the wording

Answer (score 18):

This compiles because the `+` is being interpreted as unary plus, which will perform the integral promotions on integral or enumeration types and the result will have the type of the promoted operand.

Assuming `e` is an integral or unscoped enumeration type would end up having the integral promotions applied anyway since `*` applies the *usual arithmetic conversions* to its operands which ends up at the *integral promotions* for integral types.

From the draft C++ standard `5.3.1` *[expr.unary.op]*:

> The operand of the unary + operator shall have arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, or pointer type and the
>   result is the value of the argument. Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration operands.
>   The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.

The integral promotions are covered in section `4.5`  *[conv.prom]* and if the variables `e` is a type other than `bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t` and have conversion rank less than *int* then it would be covered by paragraph `1`:

> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion
>   rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all
>   the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned
>   int.

For a complete set of cases we can look at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_promotion).

Unary plus can also be useful in some cases to resolve ambiguity, an interesting case would be from [Resolving ambiguous overload on function pointer and std::function for a lambda using +](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17822131/1708801).

Note, for those answers, referring to unary `-` and negative values, this is misleading, as this example shows:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned  x1 = 1 ;

    std::cout <<  -x1 << std::endl ;
}
```

which results in:

```
4294967295
```

See it live [using gcc on wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/D1Os6rZyCEot3il7).

It is interesting to note that unary plus was added to C99 for symmetry with unary minus, from the  [Rationale for International Standard—Programming Languages—C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf):

> Unary plus was adopted by the C89 Committee from several implementations, for symmetry with unary minus.

and I can not come up with a good case where casting would not be sufficient to achieve the same desired promotion/conversion. The lambda example I cite above, using unary plus to force a lambda expression to be converted to a function pointer:

```
foo( +[](){} ); // not ambiguous (calls the function pointer overload)
```

could be accomplished using a explicit cast:

```
foo( static_cast<void (*)()>( [](){} ) );
```

and it could be argued this code is better since the intention is explicit.

Worth noting that [Annotated C++ Reference Manual(*ARM*)](http://www.stroustrup.com/arm.html) it has the following commentary:

> Unary plus is a historical accident and generally useless.

Answer (score 9):

As what they have explained, (+) and (-) were just used as unary operator:

> [Unary operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hetcw0tx.aspx) act on only one operand in an expression

```
int value = 6;
int negativeInt = -5;
int positiveInt = +5;

cout << (value * negativeInt); // 6 * -5 = -30
cout << (value * positiveInt); // 6 * +5 = 30

cout << (value * - negativeInt); // 6 * -(-5) = 30
cout << (value * + negativeInt); // 6 * +(-5) = -30

cout << (value * - positiveInt); // 6 * -(+5) = -30
cout << (value * + positiveInt); // 6 * +(+5) = 30
```

so from your code:

```
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;
int e = 5;

int a = b * (c * d *  + e)

//result: 2 * (3 * 4 * (+5) ) = 120
```

Answer (score 5):

Why does it compile? It compiles because `+` is parsed as unary plus operator, not the addition operator. The compiler tries to parse as much as possible without generating syntax errors. So this:

```
d * + e
```

Is parsed as:

- `d` (operand)
- `*` (multiplication operator)
- `+` (unary plus operator)

  - `e` (operand)

Whereas, this:

```
d*++e;
```

Is parsed as:

- `d` (operand)
- `*` (multiplication operator)
- `++` (pre increment operator)

  - `e` (operand)

Moreover, this:

```
d*+++e;
```

Is parsed as:

- `d` (operand)
- `*` (multiplication operator)
- `++` (pre increment operator)

  - `+` (unary plus operator)

    - `e` (operand)

Note that it does not create a syntax error but the "LValue requrired" compiler error.

Answer (score 4):

To put a further twist on the correct answers already given here, if you compile with the -s flag, the C compiler will output an assembly file in which actual the instructions generated can be examined. With the following C code:

```
int b=1, c=2, d=3, e=4;
int a = b * (c * d *  + e);
```

The generated assembly (using gcc, compiling for amd64) begins with:

```
    movl    $1, -20(%ebp)
    movl    $2, -16(%ebp)
    movl    $3, -12(%ebp)
    movl    $4, -8(%ebp)
```

so we can identify individual memory positions -20(%ebp) as variable b, down to -8(%ebp) as variable e. -4(%epp) is variable a. Now, the calculation is rendered as:

```
    movl    -16(%ebp), %eax
    imull   -12(%ebp), %eax
    imull   -8(%ebp), %eax
    imull   -20(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
```

So, as has been commented by other people replying, the compiler simply treats "+e" as the unary positive operation. The first movl instruction places the contents of variable e into the EAX accumulator register, which is then promptly multiplied by the contents of variable d or -12(%ebp), etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is just basic math. For example:

```
5 * -4 = -20

5 * +4 = 5 * 4 = 20 

-5 * -4 = 20
```

**Negative * Negative = Positive**

**Positive * Negative = Negative**

**Positive * Positive = Positive**

This is the easiest explanation there is.

The minus(-) and plus(+) just tell if the number is positive or negative.

Comment: it's not like that, how about this: `int a = -5; int val = -a; //result val: 5`

Comment: `--5` becomes `4` :p  `-(-5) = 5`..just kidding i know it's just a typo.. yeah you're right :) +1

Answer (score -1):

The + operator between d and e will be treated as an unary + operator  which will determine only sign of e.
So the compiler will see this statement as follow:

```
int a = b*(c*d*e) ;
```

Comment: "which will determine only sign of e" How so?

Comment: I meant to say that + sign will work as +5 ,iff e=5..like that.